# Add color gradient color on bar HIghchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I try to add a gradient for the bar on highchart

I try this

```
colors: [{
    linearGradient: perShapeGradient,
    stops: [
      [0, '#c2352b'],
      [1, '#f44336 ']
    ]
  }, {
    linearGradient: perShapeGradient,
    stops: [
      [0, '#1b75bf'],
      [1, '#2196f3']
    ]
  }, {
    linearGradient: perShapeGradient,
    stops: [
      [0, '#cc7a00'],
      [1, '#ff9800']
    ]}, 
          ]
```

but all my bar's color become all the same (even have a gradient color).
Here's a link for full code [demo here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dmEozp).

Comment: Hi @vandi, did my answer below solved for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The thing is, you set the color for the whole series and all your data is from the same series. If you put another series you can see that it assumes another color: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XEwdQm?editors=0010

What you can do to set different color for each `category` is to set the `colorByPoint` property in `plotOptions` to `true`:

```
plotOptions: {
   colorByPoint: true
}
```

Here is the example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoLzjL?editors=0010

Comment: sorry for take it too long